# What is Flip's ethnicity?

Tags: movie, comics, anime, character-identification, animation

In the *Little Nemo in Slumberland* comic strip written by Winsor McCay (and the famous animated film written by Jean "Moebius" Giraud, Yutaka Fujioka, Chris Columbus, and Richard Outten, and directed by Masami Hata, and William Hurtz), Flip is a redeemed mischievous clown outlaw who is an on-and-off antagonist to Little Nemo. He seems to be human, but at the same time, he has greenish skin. If anything, I think his design kind of evokes the "Greasy Italian" stereotype, or the "Irish Troublemaker" stereotype, or the "West-African Buffoon" stereotype, or the "Festive Spaniard" stereotype, or the "Weird Portuguese Drug Addict" stereotype, or the "Vulgar Messy Frenchman" stereotype, or the "Cynical Semite" stereotype, or the "Drunk Slav" stereotype, or the "Chain-smoking Englishman" stereotype, or even all of those tropes.

Comment: Irishman is the general stereotype being noted in the articles I've read. Possibly relevant, when the stage play was running, under McCay's direction, he hired [Billy B. Van](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_B._Van), a noted American vaudeville performer, to play Flip.

Comment: Irish and black, according to this source; https://books.google.nl/books?id=UbS62_iyhjAC&pg=PA52&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=irish&f=false

Comment: Also here, mentioning that the Irish were considered by some to be a 'sub-White' race; http://www.kleefeldoncomics.com/2016/02/on-sims-flip.html

Comment: Note that bump-editing a post is discouraged. Edits should be substantive.